# How to set SSH proxy user in PhpStorm to connect to MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, ssh, phpstorm, mysql-workbench

In MySQL Workbench you can specify SSH Password and other SSH settings to connect to a server/database.. But in PhpStorm (v10.0.4) you can only specify either passphrase or proxy password but not both:
[image: PhpStorm vs MySQL Workbench]

**So how can I specify both parameters in PhpStorm?** Because now I'm not able to connect to the database in PhpStorm but I am able to do it in MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using an SSH key to connect to your account then you may have a passphrase you created with your ssh key that you'll need to put in. If you want to connect to SSH via password authentication, this is different and does not use the SSH key. This is the password associated with the account you're logging into, the passphrase is the key associated with the SSH key if you created one with it.

You only can login via one authentication or the other. MySQL workbench may let you add both, but it will only use one of them.